# Oracle Test Container throwing SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01918: user does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, testcontainers-junit5

I am new to **Oracle Container** and I'm having a test container to open 2 database connections since I have 2 datasource in my spring boot application.

This is the abstract class where I create Oracle container instances:

```java
@Slf4j
public class AbstractContanierBaseTest {

    static final OracleContainer ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER;
    static final OracleContainer ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER;

    static {
        ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim");
        ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER
                .withUsername("opiowner")
                .withPassword("password")
                .withDatabaseName("OPIOWNER")
                .withExposedPorts(1521)
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))
                .withEnv("ORACLE_DATABASE", "OPIOWNER")
                .withEnv("ORACLE_PASSWORD", "password")
                .withEnv("APP_USER", "opiowner")
                .withEnv("APP_USER_PASSWORD", "password")
                .usingSid();
        ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.start();

        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getDriverClassName());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getPassword());

        ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:11-slim");
        ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER
                .withUsername("firmaowner")
                .withPassword("password")
                .withDatabaseName("FIRMAOWNER")
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))
                .withEnv("ORACLE_PASSWORD", "password")
                .withEnv("APP_USER", "firmaowner")
                .withEnv("APP_USER_PASSWORD", "password")
                .usingSid();
        ;
        ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.start();

        System.setProperty("spring.second-datasource.url", ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.second-datasource.username", ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("spring.second-datasource.password", ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.getPassword());

    }
```

This class inherited by my integration tests written in junit5.

When executing junits an Sql script is launched before tests by means of `@Sql` annotation:

```java
@Sql(config = @SqlConfig(transactionManager = "opiownerTransactionManager"), scripts = {"classpath:scripts/ddl/Recall_create_table_opiConfluenzaDati.sql", "classpath:scripts/dml/Recall_opiConfluenzaDati_script.sql"})
```

The script is executed properly, but I receive an oracle `SqlSyntaxException` as per Question title.

This is my create table script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE opiowner.OPI_CONFLUENZA_DATI
(
    "OPI_ANNO_EMISSIONE_TITOLO" NUMBER(4,0),
    "OPI_TIPOLOGIADISPOSIZIONE" VARCHAR2(11),
    "OPI_DATADISPOSIZIONE" DATE,
    "OPI_ID_DISPOSIZIONE" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    "OPI_NUM_TITOLO" NUMBER(9,0),
    "OPI_PROG_QUOTA" NUMBER(15,0),
    "OPI_TIPO_COD_BENEF" VARCHAR2(2),
    "OPI_CODICE_BENEF" VARCHAR2(16),
    "OPI_TIPO_RECORD" VARCHAR2(11),
    "OPI_SPECIE_TITOLO" VARCHAR2(2),
    "OPI_TIPO_SPESA" VARCHAR2(5),
    "OPI_COD_ENTE" VARCHAR2(15),
    "OPI_IMPORTO" NUMBER(15,3),
    "OPI_NOME_FILE" VARCHAR2(100),
    "OPI_ORDINANTE" VARCHAR2(100)
);

ALTER TABLE opiowner.OPI_CONFLUENZA_DATI
ADD CONSTRAINT OPI_CONFLUENZA_DATI_PK PRIMARY KEY ("OPI_TIPOLOGIADISPOSIZIONE", "OPI_DATADISPOSIZIONE", "OPI_ID_DISPOSIZIONE");
```

As you may guess I need the 'opiowner' user to be present in the database. In particular in the first instance of the Oracle container: `ORACLE_OPIOWNER` firstly.

**Question:** How can I create 'opiowner' user in a Oracle Container instance?

I thought methods `withUsername` and `withPassword` would do the trick, but they do not...

So as you can see with method `withEnv` I tried to override environment variables of the Docker image, but again no way...

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. Create sql script init.sql with : CREATE USER OPIOWNER IDENTIFIED BY "password" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE TO OPIOWNER; Then on initialization of testcontainers add : ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.withInitScript("component/db/init.sql")

Comment: Hi @zpavel, thanks for your attention. I tried and I get ORA-01031:insufficient privileges...

Comment: Sorry i coulent not ediit but it was : ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.withInitScript("init.sql"). So i suppose your init.sql was loaded as well (and you modified it). After which query it shows ora-01031 error?

Comment: @zpavel, Yes, correct.

Comment: Please add the error in the question and also is there any way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @AnishB. your answer has disappeared...

Comment: Hi. I deleted my answer. I felt it was not helping you.

Comment: Can you tell me if you have privilege to create any account in your test container.

Comment: It seems I do not have any privilege

Comment: So, without privilege, you can't create a user.

Comment: Can you put the create user statement in init.sql and execute it to see if it works? Which version of the test containers are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the issue that you are facing. Kindly go through this **Github issue** below:

[[OracleContainer] Unable to execute statements which need system privileges](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4615)

**Note:** I'm not a DB Expert.

Based on the information provided there, I've formed my answer which is as follows:

- For an `oracle-xe` image, now the default user and schema is now "**TEST**".
- I guess you won't be able to create any random user where you don't have the privileges. To overcome that, you have to use **TEST** user which is kind of acts as a super-user for test containers (Oracle Test containers uses/detects **TEST** as the default user).
- So, what can I suggest is to create an **init.sql** some like this below:

  ```
  CREATE USER OPIOWNER IDENTIFIED BY password;
  GRANT CONNECT TO OPIOWNER;
  GRANT SYSDBA TO OPIOWNER;
  GRANT CREATE SESSION GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE TO OPIOWNER;
  GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO OPIOWNER;
  ```
- Update **AbstractContanierBaseTest** class to some like this:

  ```
    @Slf4
    public class AbstractContanierBaseTest {

    static final OracleContainer ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER;
    static final OracleContainer ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER;

    static {
        ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim");
        ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER
                .withUsername("test")
                .withInitScript("init.sql");
                .usingSid();
        ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.start();

        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getDriverClassName());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", ORACLE_OPIOWNER_CONTANINER.getPassword());

        ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:11-slim").withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("init.sql"), "/container-entrypoint-startdb.d/init.sql");
        ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER
                .withUsername("firmaowner")
                .withPassword("password")
                .withDatabaseName("FIRMAOWNER")
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))
                .withEnv("ORACLE_PASSWORD", "password")
                .withEnv("APP_USER", "firmaowner")
                .withEnv("APP_USER_PASSWORD", "password")
                .usingSid();
        ;
        ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.start();

        System.setProperty("spring.second-datasource.url", ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.second-datasource.username", ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("spring.second-datasource.password", ORACLE_FIRMAOWNER_CONTANINER.getPassword());

    }
  ```
- Now, update the create table script to this:

  ```
    ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=<<NAME OF TEST CONTAINER>>;

    CREATE TABLE TEST.OPI_CONFLUENZA_DATI
    (
        "OPI_ANNO_EMISSIONE_TITOLO" NUMBER(4,0),
        "OPI_TIPOLOGIADISPOSIZIONE" VARCHAR2(11),
        "OPI_DATADISPOSIZIONE" DATE,
        "OPI_ID_DISPOSIZIONE" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
        "OPI_NUM_TITOLO" NUMBER(9,0),
        "OPI_PROG_QUOTA" NUMBER(15,0),
        "OPI_TIPO_COD_BENEF" VARCHAR2(2),
        "OPI_CODICE_BENEF" VARCHAR2(16),
        "OPI_TIPO_RECORD" VARCHAR2(11),
        "OPI_SPECIE_TITOLO" VARCHAR2(2),
        "OPI_TIPO_SPESA" VARCHAR2(5),
        "OPI_COD_ENTE" VARCHAR2(15),
        "OPI_IMPORTO" NUMBER(15,3),
        "OPI_NOME_FILE" VARCHAR2(100),
        "OPI_ORDINANTE" VARCHAR2(100)
     );

     ALTER TABLE TEST.OPI_CONFLUENZA_DATI
     ADD CONSTRAINT OPI_CONFLUENZA_DATI_PK PRIMARY KEY ("OPI_TIPOLOGIADISPOSIZIONE", "OPI_DATADISPOSIZIONE", "OPI_ID_DISPOSIZIONE");
  ```

See if this changes work. That's all. Look at that github issue for more info.

Comment: Dear @Anish, your answer makes arise a doubt in my mind. In the code under test, entities are defined with schemas. So when a query Is done in a table of firmaowner user hibernate adds the user before any select or insert. I think, as I tried, that  if i use the tecnique you have suggested, the same exceprion User does not exist Will be thrown... Indeed, I tried to create the tables without indicating a user, and the tables have bene created, but the exceprion Is thrown

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola First of all, are you able to create any user? Because you said that you were not able to create user right?

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola First try with 1 datasource and execute the query, see what issues are you facing?

Comment: Hi @Anish, I'm not able to execute the script because of error Sql = CONNECT TEST/password@OPIOWNER, OriginalSql = CONNECT TEST/password@OPIOWNER, Error Msg = ORA-00900: invalid sql statement. Anyway, thing is that I need to create the table for OPIOWNER user and not for TEST. I am not able to create any user...

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola I have already mentioned in my answer that you won't be able to create because you don't have privileges. That's why you need to use TEST and I also mentioned the github issue which you have to read to get some conclusion..

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola `CONNECT TEST/<pwd>@<<NAME OF TEST CONTAINER>>`. Is the name of the container `OPIOWNER`?

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola You can skip Connect sql and try the rest of the sql with test.

Comment: I get ORA-01918:User TEST does not exist...

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Can you try this -> SELECT *
FROM master.sys.database_principals; to see how many users are there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255328/discussion-between-anish-b-and-saverio-mirko-viola).

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Can you try this please? and reply me now itself.

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola I have updated my answer. Please verify if this is working now.

Comment: Dear @AnishB, Unfortunately user 'sys as sysdba' is not allowed. If I put sys or system, withUsername() method throws an exception. I am using version 1.19.0.

Comment: I understand from container logs that the sys user exists and is called test: CREATE USER sys as sysdba IDENTIFIED BY "test" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS.
So probably I need to connect to test to create new users... right?

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Yes!

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Then I was correct earlier about 'test' user in the container.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how can create OPIOWNER user by means of TEST?

Comment: The whole thing is messing me up

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Yes I can explain. Just give me a min.

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Are you connected to test user?

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Just try `connect sys/"<pwd>@test" as sysdba` and then execute the create user statement for OPIOWNER.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255374/discussion-between-anish-b-and-saverio-mirko-viola).

Comment: Dear @Anish, forgive be for being so late but I was real busy in these days. Given the difficulties in solving this problem, we, me and our team, decided to change our path.
Anyway, to let yot know, the last instruction gives the following error: CONNECT sys/"password@test" as sysdba: invalid sql statement

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola Ok no problem.